# Use select_related for comma separated field

Tags: python, django, csv, django-select-related

I have two class model like this:

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    services = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=200)

class Services(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

As you see in Problem model I keep id's of Services in comma separated field. For example to solve this problem we should do this Services: "1,2,3". I want to show detail of problem and related services to user. To do this I should join Problem to Services table but I don't know how. Consider that I have limited number of Services that defined by super admin. for example I have 150 services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ManyToManyField`, this is exactly what they are used for.

Comment: I don't want to use ManyToManyField because when I can use comma separated field to hold services why I use another table?

Comment: Duh -- so that you can use it for joins, select_related, and so on. If you want Django and the database to do your work for you, you'll have to tell them that something is a many to many relation. And why is a 200-max-length char field that has to be interpreted as comma seperated integers any better than another table?

Comment: So we haven't comma separated with relation field in django?
So you suggest I use another table in this situation?

Comment: Exactly, comma separated relations don't exist in relational databases, so not in Django either. Use a ManyToManyField (which will create another table in the background, but you usually will never notice).

Comment: If I use another table , for one problem, for example, I have 3 raw that have id of problem and id of service. I feel this is not good structure

Answer (score 0):

Use Services that contains a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). Thus you can relate all service to one problem

Comment: I have limited number of services that defined by super admin. for example 150 services. in Problem table I use this services to know witch service should be done to solve the problem

Comment: @user2141833 what do you mean. You still can access all the Services that are related to the problem by using `choice_set.all`

Comment: @having a separted integer field is definitely not "The django way". You can have any information you want using a foreign key

Comment: Any service have their field, for example have price , unit and etc. I may have many problem to use this services. So I can't use foreign key of problem in my services table